# ZeroMQ: several I/O threads but only of them in user code?

Tags: thread-safety, zeromq

By default, there is only one thread doing I/O in ZeroMQ. Thus, there will be no more than one  of such threads in user code, in the case that we are using callbacks, like in Node.js:

```
aSocket.on ('message', function(request) { ... user code ... } );
```

But, at least in the C API, one may ask ZeroMQ to have more than one I/O thread.

In this case (several I/O threads), can we assume that no more than one I/O thread will be executing user code in callbacks?

If not true in general, at least, I guess  it is so in node.js

Comment: In the C api, there's no user supplied callbacks

Comment: Maybe, not sure, there is no problem at all if: 1) if you can have several I/O threads, then you don't use callbacks. Or 2) if you use call backs, then you can't have several threads.

Comment: Still,the C API is not callback based (Which API in particular are you actually asking about ?). It's much like the normal socket APIs. Behind the scenes zmq might use several threads, but that is marshalled back to your own thread(s) that called the socket function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer:

**In this case (several I/O threads), can we assume that no more than one I/O thread will be executing user code in callbacks?**

The ZeroMQ C library doesn't have a callback-based framework so yes we can assume that. However, as you note in your post, you can set it up to have multiple I/O threads, in which case you need to manually deal with this in your own way -- Again, no callbacks.